# Magento 2.2.5 custom js not working when I call it from phtml file using uiComponent

Tags: uicomponent, knockoutjs, adminform, magento-2.2.5

I have created admin form using uiComponent. I have called phtml file using `<htmlContent name="html_content">` in **xml** file. I tired to call **custom.js** using below code but its not working.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    { 
        "*": {
            "Namespace_Module/js/custom": {
                "Data": <?= /* @noEscape */ json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_QUOT) ?>,
                "isSortable":  <?= (int)(!$block->getReadOnly()) ?>,
                "isReadOnly": <?= (int)$block->getReadOnly() ?>
            }   
        }
    }
</script>
```

This code is working fine if I call it using simple block method without **uiComponent**.

Please let me know how can I use my custom js file with **uiComponent** form.

Comment: you have try with require ["jQuery","jQuery/ui"]]

Comment: No can you please provide code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dependencies.

```
define(['your/module/path/or/alias'],function(module){  module.useMyMethod() });
```

reference: 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html